# Buffer point issue and main thread is blocked using CoreML

Tags: swift, multithreading, pointers, buffer, coreml

I am using **CoreML** to remove the background in a given image and I have 2 major problems with it.

The model I embedded in my Xcode is `DeepLabV3.mlmodel`. This is the entire class that returns the final image: [RemoveBackgroundCoreML_Final.swift](https://gist.github.com/vlondon/491c2e7829d60e835d53a1f6810a34ed) which I just imported into my source code. It works well in terms of doing its job. However, I have a warning in this swift class at line 107:

```
let data = Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &cubeRGB, count: cubeRGB.count))
```

> Initialization of 'UnsafeMutableBufferPointer' results in a dangling buffer pointer

The worse case is, this line of the code crashes the production app according to my crash logs from the App Store for some devices, even though I myself don't experience any crash in the development environment.

This is how i call `removeBackground` method in above Swift class from my code:

```
let finalImage = image.removeBackground(returnResult: .finalImage)
```

Another issue is, above line returns `finalImage` but it also blocks the main thread in the app which has some UI animation just started to run previously to show some process (which I suspect, could be related to buffer pointer).

I hope anyone who has experience with CoreML or threading can help me and I too much appreciate it. Please ask, if further clarification needed. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not using `cubeRGB` after making the pointer to it, the Swift optimizer will deallocate it immediately afterwards. As this is an optimizer thing, you won't get this bug in debug mode, only in release mode.

`Data(buffer:...)` will make a copy of the array, so that's good. You just need to make the array stays alive until it's done copying. This can be done with `withExtendedLifetime`, something like:

```swift
let data = withExtendedLifetime(cubeRGB) {
    return Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &cubeRGB, count: cubeRGB.count))
}
```

I've probably got the syntax wrong but something like that.

Comment: You got the syntax right! But, it maintains the 'dangling buffer pointer ' warning. However, I assume it will not crash the app anymore if memory allocation is extended. But is there a way to test this in debug mode? I mean without releasing the app in-store and observing crash logs?

Comment: Maybe it's better to use `let data = cubeRGB.withUnsafeBufferPointer { ptr in Data(buffer: ptr.baseAddress!, ...)`.

Comment: There is no such syntax according to compiler, so as suggested, i modified it to `let data = cubeRGB.withUnsafeBufferPointer { ptr in Data(bytes: ptr.baseAddress!, count: cubeRGB.count) }` It will not remove the background, only returns original image.

Comment: Oh, it just should have been `Data(buffer: ptr)`.

Comment: Thank you. `let data = cubeRGB.withUnsafeBufferPointer { ptr in Data(buffer: ptr) }` worked. I will observe it on live application for sometime. I hope it does not crash anymore. By the way, for the thread issue, i have used background thread only for CoreML and sync to main thread after image is returned,